# Ruby 2.0.0 install via RVM: errors surrounding openssl

Tags: macos, ruby, openssl

Using: `Mountain Lion 10.8.2`, `RVM 1.18.15`

Having trouble with, *apparently*, `openssl` when trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 via RVM:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
...
Extracting openssl to /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc -I/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr/include -L/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr/lib zlib no-asm no-krb5 --prefix=/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr no-shared ', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/configure.log
Compiling openssl in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/make.log
```

so I `brew install openssl` to update openssl to `1.0.1e` hoping that would help but there were still more errors (see "long output").

So, dug around Stack Exchange and loosely followed suggestion on [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74643/problems-installing-ruby-versions-via-rvm-in-mountain-lion) which recommended `rvm get head` (as opposed to my typical `rvm get stable`) and noticed:

```
$ rvm get head
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
...
100 1620k  100 1620k    0     0   275k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  479k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/meltemi/.bashrc /Users/meltemi/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/meltemi/.bash_profile /Users/meltemi/.zshrc.
    Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsets ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Interesting bit being `cannot load such file -- openssl`.

What gives?

## long output:

after updating openssl to 1.0.1.e via homebrew tried again but for whatever reason 1.0.1c is still being referenced:

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local          
Removing /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0...
Removing /Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0...
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/meltemi/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc -I/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr/include -L/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr/lib zlib no-asm no-krb5 --prefix=/Users/meltemi/.rvm/usr --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local no-shared ', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/configure.log
Compiling openssl in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl.certs.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.0 for ruby-2.0.0-p0 ...
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /Users/meltemi/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/setup.rb', please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/Users/meltemi/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time ...
Install of ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #complete 
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0 pristine.
Error running '' under ,
please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gemset.pristine.log
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0@global pristine.
Error running '' under ,
please read /Users/meltemi/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gemset.pristine.log
```

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading to OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had the same problem. Try the following:

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0
```

Comment: what, exactly, does the `--autolibs=3` flag do? I can't find *any* documentation on it…

Comment: FWIW- I followed your instructions, kind of: `remove 2.0.0` and then `rvm get head` (ignoring the `--autolibs=3` bit). checked requirements. OK. then `rvm install ruby-2.0.0`. and...no problems! It worked!

Comment: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1623 There is some info on `autolibs` flag, as far as I understand, it tells RVM how to handle additional required libs.

Comment: Documentation for autolibs can be found by running the following cmd: "rvm help autolibs" from the terminal

Comment: Under OSX 10.8: also `sudo brew install openssl`

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall all --force
```

I also had `rvm autolibs rvm_pkg` for readline support.