# 'which openssl' returns nothing when trying to upgrade OpenSSL

Tags: macos, homebrew, openssl, rvm

I've been working the last day or so to get openssl upgraded on my machine. I've followed the answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83885/ruby-2-0-0-install-via-rvm-errors-surrounding-openssl) and now I've got some pretty funny results.

When I type `which openssl` I get no response.
When I type `openssl version` I get `-bash: openssl: command not found`
When I type `brew install openssl` I get `Warning: openssl-1.0.1g already installed.`

Why does brew recognize an installation, but my other terminal commands suggest that nothing is installed? What do I need to do to get my system to recognize the installation that brew is seeing, or what do I need to remove to allow me to do a fresh install of openssl?

Edit: 'brew doctor' gives me the following:

> Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.4) is outdated
>   Please install XQuartz 2.7.5:
>    https://xquartz.macosforge.org
>
> Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
>
> Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
>   brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
>   with other software installs.

Comment: What does `brew doctor` give?

Comment: Post edited to include what is provided by the 'brew doctor' command.

Answer (score 1):

This command should show you where any openssl binaries may be located on your system:

`locate openssl | grep bin/openssl`

For homebrew, make sure you have /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin in your $PATH. You can check your current path setting by issuing `echo $PATH`.

Comment: When I run locate I get a warning about the locate database not being created.

Comment: ah, then you can run:

`sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

that will run a complete filesystem sweep of your system and store all information about files and directories in a locate database. You can then run the `locate` command after it has run to find the openssl files.

Comment: There are of course other ways to achieve the same thing. Another is to use spotlight's terminal command: 

`mdfind 'kMDItemFSName=openssl&&kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like openssl was installed in /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/bin/openssl and needed to be symlinked to the desired location. The following command accomplished that for me:

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin

After that command was run, 'which openssl' returned "/usr/local/bin/openssl" and 'openssl version' returned "OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014"